# Dynamic Range in []

Tags: r

I want to pick something from a dataset with data[1:5].

How can I make the range [1:5] dynamic? The number 5 should be based on a different integer. Somehow, I cant find it online.

I have tried:

```
integer <- 5
range <- paste0('1:',integer,collapse=)
```

-> result is "1:5"

```
data[range]
```

-> does not work

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This surely has to be a duplicate but... did you ever try 1:integer directly? That approach has it's own problems especially if 'integer' is dynamic but it's a starting point.  You might just want to consider the `seq` function and it's many variations instead though.

Comment: Agree with @dason, but if you insist, you could do something like this: `data[eval(parse(text=range))]`

Comment: I agree - you can simply do `range <- seq(integer)`

Comment: `paste` produces a string, so `date[range]` could only be useful with `date <- list("1:5"=c(...))`. The only way you can create an expression like that in a string and expect it to be parsed and evaluated as such is to do `eval(parse(text=range))` (hsl), which works, but is a in my opinion mistake: meta-programming and the use of `eval(parse(..))` is inefficient and difficult to troubleshoot if/when things go wrong. Before you go down the path of trying to parse strings and (passively or actively) evaluate the dynamic strings, I suggest going the direct route as suggested (twice).